# How can I select images on vue using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to create with vue.js a radio button (bootstrap) where I can select the image to visualize.
I created 3 buttons for 3 images but I can't connect them (of course the previous image must disappear).

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-group label="Map to visualize">
          <b-form-checkbox-group
            v-model="map.value"
            :options="map.options"
            name="buttonsMap"
            buttons
          ></b-form-checkbox-group>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row class="map">
      <b-col cols="9">
        <h3>Map</h3>

        <div id="app">
          <img :src="require('./image/Map1.png')" height="400" />
        </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Rad',
  data() {
    return {
      map: {
        value: 'Map1',
        options: ['Map1', 'Map2', 'Map3'],
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

This works, but I can only see one map. I wanna add 3 of them connected with the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `img` `src` must include a dynamic value for the different `img` paths:

```html
<div id="app">
  <img :src="'require(./image/' + map.value + '.png)'" height="400">
</div>
```

here is a Demo : [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/eYOgbWo?editors=1111)

Comment: It doesn't work, I have a parsing error or something

Comment: i fixed a little syntax error where the '+' was inside `./image/+'` make sure you update with the updated solution

Comment: seems it works but the images crashed. I can see only the symbol. U know the possible reason?

Comment: @HugoB does your 2nd and 3rd images have exactly the following paths `'./image/Map2.png'` & `'./image/Map3.png'` ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: @HugoB gotta be something wrong with the images.... maybe they are not pngs or something cuz i  copied &  pasted your code into the [codpen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/eYOgbWo?editors=1111) sample and it works fine .

Comment: I think the problem is in the code. I tried with Map1, with the simple <img :src="require('./image/Map1.png')" height="400" /> and the same image works. I tried to delate the other 2 images and with this code didn't work

Comment: @HugoB just check the sample that i provided and try to compare

Comment: @HugoB Or provide a code demo and it shall be fixed